# DataContractJsonSerializer with NetworkStream

Tags: c#, networkstream, datacontractjsonserializer

i want to use the DataContractJsonSerializer class in combination with the TcpClient to receive and send JSON serialized objects. I am able to send JSON serialized objects but the receiving part does not work.

Source code of sending objects:

```
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, tcpPort);
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
tcpClient.Connect(endPoint);
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(....));
 ser.WriteObject(tcpClient.GetStream(), req);
```

Source code of receiving objects:

```
var deser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(...));
var resp = (....)deser.ReadObject(tcpClient.GetStream());
```

The method ReadObject is hanging.
Can anyone tell me the issue and how I can solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Comment: You may have a timing issue.  The receiving code will only read what is in the buffer and not wait until all the data is received.  So adding a network stream to the tclclient stream may be needed to wait.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=net-6.0

Comment: Thanks @jdweng
How can i wrap the tcpclient into the network stream ?

Comment: Assuming you are flushing the stream on the client side, I believe that the reader returned by [`JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory.createjsonreader) is trying to read beyond the last JSON token to confirm the entire stream is well-formed JSON (i.e. no garbage at end) and hangs doing that.

Comment: For similar issues see [XmlSerializer Won't Deserialize over NetworkStream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28492295/3744182) or [protobuf-net fails deserializing my class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8901333/3744182).

Comment: I cannot close the tcp client connection or call the shutdown method, because there should be multiple transmissions.
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Use [message framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html).  When sending either serialize to a local MemoryStream then write the number of bytes into the NetworkStream as a prefix to each message, or use some sentinel character that never appears in well-formed UTF8 XML such as `'\0'` to mark the end of each message.  Then when receiving, read only the specified number of bytes / only until the sentinel into a local MemoryStream, then deserialize from that.

Comment: See e.g. [How to create TCP message framing for the stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47382719) or [TcpClient.GetStream().DataAvailable returns false, but stream has more data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9088533/3744182) or [TCP client\server - client doesn't always read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12699292/3744182).  In fact this could be a duplicate of those, agree?